# ¿ Como puedo quitar el espacio al final del output en Python?

Tags: python

tengo que extraer correos y cuando los imprimo en el output me aparece un espacio que no me deja completar el test.

```
text="mbox-short.txt"
handler=open(text)

for lineas in handler:
    lineas.split()
    if lineas.startswith`("From ")`:
        newlineas=lineas.split()
        correos=newlineas[1]
        print(correos)
```

Si elimino el espacio del ("From ") me aparecen otros correos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica también una selección de los datos del archivo; una que muestre el problema.

Comment: no creo que a la gente le guste que publiques sus emails... proporciona un [example] para que podamos reproducir el problema. Lee [ask] también

Comment: Hola, estos correos estan publicos en una pagina

Comment: ¿Y cual sería esa página? Tampoco entendi a cual "espacio" te refieres. ¿Una línea en blanco al final? ¿Un espacio antes/después de la dirección?

Comment: Lo siento por ser tan poco específico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada mensaje en ese archivo consta de dos partes: el header SMTP y el texto mismo del correo.

Este es el header SMTP, que muestra todo el camino recorrido por email:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])
     by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3
Received: from murder ([unix socket])
     by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
... etc, más de lo mismo ...
```

El header comienza con un From que indica el remitente y la fecha/hora del mensaje.

Luego, aun dentro del encabezado, viene la parte que se te muestra

```
To: source@collab.sakaiproject.org
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
Subject: [sakai] svn commit: r39772 - content/branches/sakai_2-5-x/content-impl/
```

Este "From: " es lo que te muestra tu cliente de correo.

Como vez, existen lineas que comienzan con "From " y otras con "From: "

Cuando seleccionas lineas que comienzan con "From ", sólo encuentras una dirección dentro de cada correo.

Cuando seleccionas con "From", encuentras dos direcciones: las que comienzan con "From " y "From:". Ambas deberían ser iguales.

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
```

Ojo: también puede haber una linea que comience con "From" dentro del texto del mensaje.

Si quieres evitar la línea en blanco al final, hazlo asi:

```
text="mbox-short.txt"
handler=open(text)

primera = True
for lineas in handler:
    lineas.split()
    if lineas.startswith("From"):
        if not primera:
            print()
        newlineas=lineas.split()
        correos=newlineas[1]
        print(correos, end="")
        primera = False
```